# How to get count of NULL records in one-to-many join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, null

I have a `account` and `plan` table in which a user's account can have none or single/multiple or inactive plans associated to it at a given time.

`account` Table:

```
+---------+-------------+---+
|   ID    | account_id  | ..|
+---------+-------------+---+
|   1     |   111111    |   |
|   2     |   222222    |   |
|   3     |   333333    |   |
|   4     |   444444    |   |
+---------+-------------+---+
```

`plan` Table:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |     account_id     | attribute_key  | attribute_value | start_date          | end_date            |
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |             111111 |      RPC       | AB              | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | NULL                |
|  2 |             111111 |      RPC       | CND             | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | NULL                |
|  3 |             222222 |      RPC       | IA              | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 |             222222 |      RPC       | CND             | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  5 |             333333 |      RPC       | IA              | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  6 |             333333 |      RPC       | CND             | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | NULL                |
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Associated plan is considered active if the `end_date` is `NULL`.
Am trying to come up with a query which would return the list or count of accounts which only have `inactive` plans associated to it. Based on the above it would be `222222` as it has two plans associated with it but both are marked as inactive.:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id |     account_id     | attribute_key  | attribute_value | start_date          | end_date            |
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  3 |             222222 |      RPC       | IA              | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
|  4 |             222222 |      RPC       | CND             | 2011-10-01 00:00:00 | 2015-04-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? It is hard to figure out what exactly you have problems with. Is it the check on `NULL` ? Is it the dependency on other records?

Comment: I am unclear what you want as output the question title seems to say count but the question body seems to say give me all rows per account id where all plans are inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Derived Table (subquery), you can get the list of `account_id` values which has only "inactive plans":

```
SELECT account_id 
FROM plan 
GROUP BY account_id 
HAVING COUNT(end_date IS NULL) = 0 /* No plan with null end date */
```

Now, you can use this subquery to join back to the `plan` table, to get all the plans for that `account_id`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM plan AS p 
JOIN (
       SELECT account_id 
       FROM plan 
       GROUP BY account_id 
       HAVING COUNT(end_date IS NULL) = 0
     ) AS dt ON dt.account_id = p.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it OK.

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    Plan
INNER JOIN Account a USING (account_id)
WHERE p.account_id NOT IN (
    SELECT p2.account_id FROM Plan p2 WHERE p2.end_date IS NULL
);
```